# Obtaining value from Json using Gson get()

Tags: java, json, gson

Given the following Json data:

```
 "values": [
{
  "type": "any",
  "value": "MO918038B",
  "key": "nino"
},
{
  "type": "any",
  "value": "1956-11-18",
  "key": "dob"
},
{
  "type": "any",
  "value": "q",
  "key": "memorableWord"
},
{
  "type": "any",
  "value": "E13468",
  "key": "pin"
},
]
```

And the following Java class:

```
    public void doStuff() {

    try (Reader reader = new FileReader("global-vars.json")) {

        JsonObject json = new Gson().fromJson(reader, JsonObject.class);

        String reg = json.get("values").toString();

        System.out.println(reg);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I'm not clear, after searching, how best to obtain the "value" of, for example, "nino" which is = "MO918038B"

Comment: I don't know gson but I assume that `json.get("values")` returns a `JsonArray` or something similar. Did you read the documentation on that? Did you try iterating over that array/list?

Comment: Either you iterate through it, or you can convert the json into classes/Objects and work with that like any other java object.

Comment: @ChristophS thanks - this is the ideal I think, I just haven't used Gson or Jackson before so was unaware as to where to start with this kind of key:value json data

Answer (score 0):

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<YourObjectClass>>() {}.getType();
List<YourObjectClass> yourList = new Gson().fromJson(yourJson, listType);
```

Comment: please, add some explanation to your answer

Comment: You should define a parsing Type in order to convert your json string to a Java Object. You can archive that defining a Type variable (row 1) by TyleToken constructor providing a list of your objects. Then (row 2) you can use a Gson parser to obtain a concrete list of object providing the json and the previously defined Type.

Answer (score 0):

Since your posted JSON isn't RFC 4627 conformant, I assume this array is inside of an object.

Code would look like this:

```
public class YourClass {
    class Value {
        public String type;
        public String value;
        public String key;
    }
    public Value[] values;
}


public class App{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{ \"values\": [\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "  \"type\": \"any\",\n" +
                "  \"value\": \"MO918038B\",\n" +
                "  \"key\": \"nino\"\n" +
                "},\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "  \"type\": \"any\",\n" +
                "  \"value\": \"1956-11-18\",\n" +
                "  \"key\": \"dob\"\n" +
                "},\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "  \"type\": \"any\",\n" +
                "  \"value\": \"q\",\n" +
                "  \"key\": \"memorableWord\"\n" +
                "},\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "  \"type\": \"any\",\n" +
                "  \"value\": \"E13468\",\n" +
                "  \"key\": \"pin\"\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "]}";
        YourClass yourClass = new Gson().fromJson(json, YourClass.class);

        for (YourClass.Value value : yourClass.values) {
            if (value.key.equals("nino")) {
                System.out.println(value.value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```